# changing innodb_buffer_pool_size makes error

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb

i want to increase my innodb_buffer_pool_size value to get some more performance and when i try, my select queries arises error such as "Incorrect information file in .."

i'm just adding

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G 
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
```

value in my my.cnf then restart mysql service. how can i prevent these errors? Thanks for help!

Comment: Please add relevant info from mysql's error log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you change the innodb_buffer_pool_size size you need to remove the ib_logfile's usually located in /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile2 etc. This way mysql can regenerate the pool files when you restart it.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information so we can help you. Pasting what is inside the MySQL error log (usually /var/log/mysqld.log) is a great start. Also how much RAM do you have in your system? Also pasting your current /etc/my.cnf settings will help as well.